# SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax-error

No changes made to lang.js file since months ago but suddenly syntax error when trying to preview locally and can't deploy changes.

Not sure why this is happening - could somebody please kindly help? Many thanks!

Disclosure/warning: I have 0 programming knowledge.

```
MacBook:pty-bus Ying$ node index.js
/Users/Ying/Desktop/pty-bus/lang.js:19
    ...req.lang.marketing.global,
    ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:78:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Ying/Desktop/pty-bus/index.js:20:36)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
```

lang.js

```
var path = require('path');

function langMiddleware(req, res, next){
  let lang = req.query.lang || 'en';

  if(['es', 'en'].indexOf(lang) == -1) lang = 'en'

  fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'lang', lang + '.json'), 'utf8', function(err, data){
    req.lang = JSON.parse(data);
    req.langCode = lang;
    next();
  })
};


function render(req, res, template, vars={}){
  let renderObj = {
    ...req.lang.marketing.global,
    title: req.lang.titles[template],
    site_title: req.lang.site_title,
    site_description: req.lang.site_description,
    ...(req.lang.marketing[template] || {}),
    lang: {...(req.lang.marketing.global.language || {})},
    langCode: req.langCode,
    ...vars,
    path: req.path
  };

  res.render(template, renderObj);
}

module.exports = { langMiddleware, render }
```

Comment: What version of node are you using? (type `node --version`)

Comment: You lost me at `I have 0 programming knowledge`.

Comment: @Quentin v7.4.0

Comment: @Quentin Just checked, node version is correct. Just finding it really strange since I haven't touched that file in months and all my other commits and deployments have worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your ability to use spread operator has been removed. I would guess you have recently changed your node version, or edited either your babelrc or webpack config. Either way, I don't think it's anything wrong with your current code in that file.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js v7.4.0 has V8 5.4 which supports `...`operator for arrays, but not for objects. You need at least [V8 6.0](https://v8.dev/blog/v8-release-60#object-rest%2Fspread-properties), i.e. the last Node.js 8 branch version will do (v8.15.0).

Answer (score -1):

Tt looks like node v7.4.0 not support spread operator - change `let renderObj = {...}` to

```
let renderObj = {
    title: req.lang.titles[template],
    site_title: req.lang.site_title,
    site_description: req.lang.site_description,
    langCode: req.langCode,
    path: req.path
  };

Object.assign(renderObj,
  req.lang.marketing.global,
  (req.lang.marketing[template] || {}),
  vars
);  
renderObj.lang = Object.assign({}, (req.lang.marketing.global.language || {}));
```

Comment: See https://node.green/ — Node.js has supported spread syntax, without a flah, since at least 5.12.

Comment: @Quentin - nope you are wrong - i check on version 6.3.1 and "`...`" doesnt work - https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-nodejs-online

Comment: In 7.4.0, `...` works for arrays, but not for objects.